# Can we disable magento extension for particular page

Tags: magento

> how to disable a extension for particular page for example i want to disable extension for homepage only  in magento

```
<config>
<modules>
<first_module>
<active>false</active>
<codepool>local</codepool>
</first_module>
</modules>
</config>
```

Comment: does removing a module from `layout handle` of homepage would solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't confronted this kinda disabling feature that way. What we usually do is, we remove the module on the page from local.xml under the page responsible layout handle taking responsible reference.

For eg. if i don't one particular module for eg.newsletter on homepage then,

```
<cms_index_index> <!--/ Homepage -->
  <reference name="footer"> <!--/ Reference where the module appearing -->
    <remove name="newsletter"/> <!--/ Remove -->
  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: it is removing block not disabling extension,  but i think  remove name is only solution to achieve some kind of results, Thanks S.K.C

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in Magento 1.x

You can only enable/disable a module per store view or website.